# eliminate duplicates value from tuple of tuples

Tags: python, tuples

I want to retrieve a result like below using loop, one by one:

```
result=((1, 'name1', 'Noah'),(1, 'name2', 'Liam'),(2, 'name3', 'Mason'),(3, 'name5', 'Mason'))

tupe = ((1, 'name1', 'Noah'),(1, 'name2', 'Liam'),(2, 'name3', 'Mason'),(2, 'name4', 'Mason'),(3, 'name5', 'Mason'))
```

This is the code I tried, but it doesn't give the expected output:

```
for rowx in tupe:
     for rowy in tupe:
          if rowx[0] == rowy[0]:
               if rowx[2] != rowy[2]:
                   print(rowx)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I don't see any duplicates in this list of tuples. Which index are you using to determine uniqueness?

Comment: I think he means the (2, name3, Mason) and (2, name4, Mason) but not sure

Comment: I am trying to make unique of [2] index in each tuple, but [0] should be same and also if there is duplicate on [2] I want to keep one and the rest can be eliminated..

Comment: so, result = (
        (1, 'name1', 'Noah'),
        (1, 'name2', 'Liam'),
        (2, 'name3', 'Mason'),
        (3, 'name5', 'Mason')
   )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to eliminate duplicates based on indices 0 and 2:

```
tupe = ((1, 'name1', 'Noah'),
        (1, 'name2', 'Liam'),
        (2, 'name3', 'Mason'),
        (2, 'name4', 'Mason'),
        (3, 'name5', 'Mason'))

print(tuple({(x[0], x[2]): x for x in tupe[::-1]}.values())[::-1])
```

Output:

```
((1, 'name1', 'Noah'), (1, 'name2', 'Liam'), (2, 'name3', 'Mason'), (3, 'name5', 'Mason'))
```

I reversed the tuple which prioritizes elements earlier in the structure in the case of duplicates, but you can skip this component if you don't mind which of the duplicates are chosen or want to prioritize last-item-seen; it's extra work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really follow your explanation. Can you post a new question with all of the details and sample code + i/o?

Comment: posted new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52571049/eliminate-multi-string-duplicate-on-same-index-2-from-tuple-of-tuples